# Return information result to multiple input fields

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am attempting to create a simple web element that on request, retrieves the page title / meta description of a webpage by using: php / ajax / jquery.

I have it working to a point, though I am not sure how to prepare the returned information in the PHP and on success, so that the $title appears in an input field and the $description appears in a separate input field.

At the moment it just returns to one echo'ed block.

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:retrievepageinformation()" >Action request</a>

<div>The URL</div>
<input name="theaddress" type="text" id="theaddress"  value="http://">

<div>The result</div>
<input name="title" id="title"  value="" />
<input name="description" id="description"  value="" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function retrievepageinformation () {

$("#title").val('Retrieving..');
$("#description").val('Retrieving..');

var dataqueryurl = $("#theaddress").val();

$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "request-information.php",  
data: "dataqueryurl="+ dataqueryurl,  

success: function(dataresult){  
    $("#title").ajaxComplete(function(){ 
    $(this).val(dataresult);
    });
 } 

}); 

}
```

**PHP** (request-information.php)

```
if(isSet($_POST['dataqueryurl'])) {


function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$dataqueryurl = $_POST['dataqueryurl'];
$html = file_get_contents_curl($dataqueryurl);

//parsing begins here:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

// Get and display what you need:
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
{
    $meta = $metas->item($i);
    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
        $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
}


// Data to pass back to input field 'Title'
echo $title;
// Data to pass back to input field 'Description'
echo  $description;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass back information from **request-information.php** you can use concept of *array* and *json_encode*.

function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
```

}

$dataqueryurl = $_POST['dataqueryurl'];

$html = file_get_contents_curl($dataqueryurl);

//parsing begins here:

$doc = new DOMDocument();

@$doc->loadHTML($html);

$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

// Get and display what you need:

$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

$metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)

{

```
$meta = $metas->item($i);

if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description'){

    $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');

}
```

}

$result = array('title'=>$title, 'desc'=>$description);

echo json_encode($result);

}

And to **get this information** in your javascript you can use *$.parseJSON()* in the success callback of ajax.

function retrievepageinformation () {

```
$("#title").val('Retrieving..');
$("#description").val('Retrieving..');

var dataqueryurl = $("#theaddress").val();

$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "request-information.php",  
data: "dataqueryurl="+ dataqueryurl,  

success: function(dataresult){  
    dataresult = $.parseJSON(dataresult);
    $("#title").val(dataresult.title);
    $("#description").val(dataresult.desc);
 } 

});
```

}

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have been trying to learn as best as I could. The JSON was just the trick! I cannot believe how simple the logic was. Really appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 1):

> In the php side

```
echo json_encode(array("title"=>"My title","description"=>"Test description"));
```

> In the ajax success

```
success: function(dataresult){  

       $("#title").val(dataresult.title);
       $("#description").val(dataresult.description);

 }
```

**FYI**

[json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)